# Gap in the middle between Jumbotron Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I don't know why but somehow there's a background gap in the middle so the background image is divided by the content in the middle. Could you help me out?
Here's the HTML Code:

```
<div class="pertama">
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
      <h1>Aceh Bus App</h1>
      <hr class="light">
      <h2>Satu Aplikasi. Semua Bus</h2>
      <button class="btn">
        Tentang Aceh Bus App
      </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS Code:

```
.pertama {
 background: url('../img/bgbl.jpg') center center no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 height: 90%;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
position: relative;
padding-top: 180px;
text-align: center;
}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: So, instead of the gray background in the jumbotron you want to see the background image instead?

Comment: Could you share the CSS for the other elements as well please

Comment: yes, @DanOrlovsky, I find there's a gap I don't know here it came from.

Comment: When I try at JSFiddle, it works perfect, but when I try this at my mac, it's happening again.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove background from your jumbotron element:

```
.jumbotron {
  background: none;
}
```

Comment: I was about to start answering and boom.  It's here.  I'd add to make sure the user knows that custom site styles need to be added AFTER bootstrap, otherwise they'll be overwritten.

Comment: I think this is my fault, I make the background at the jumbotron first, then when I change the style to custom style, the jumbotron seems still overwritten. Can I reset the jumbotron back?